# How to tell DockerHub user vs org

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Is there a way to tell if a DockerHub account is a [user](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/accounts/#registration-for-a-docker-hub-account) or an [organization](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/accounts/#organizations-groups)?

For example, I think [this Google account](https://registry.hub.docker.com/repos/google/) is an org. I know [this account](https://registry.hub.docker.com/repos/dfarrell07/) (mine) is a user. The URL structures are identical, and I haven't been able to find an obvious sign in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This no longer works. Organizations now provide the [same curl result as users](http://pastebin.com/dYmq415u).

This is a bit of a hack, <strike>but it seems to work</strike>.

```
[~]$ curl -sI "https://hub.docker.com/u/google/" | grep "^Location: " > /dev/null && echo "Organization" || echo "User"
Organization
[~]$ curl -sI "https://hub.docker.com/u/docker/" | grep "^Location: " > /dev/null && echo "Organization" || echo "User"
Organization
[~]$ curl -sI "https://hub.docker.com/u/dfarrell07/" | grep "^Location: " > /dev/null && echo "Organization" || echo "User"
User
[~]$ curl -sI "https://hub.docker.com/u/davetucker/" | grep "^Location: " > /dev/null && echo "Organization" || echo "User"
User
```